# Why can't i see logs of code pieces triggered by AlarmManager?

Tags: android-studio, alarmmanager, intentservice

I'm very new to android studio development so the answer is probably trivial.
That being said, I've busted my head around the problem for a day now :/

I am trying to run a chunk of code every 10 seconds even when the app is closed using AlarmManager.

I copy-pasted what is suggested in this guide https://guides.codepath.com/android/Starting-Background-Services

I'm a little puzzled by the result - 
I think I do get alarm triggered every 10 seconds, as indicated in the log:

> 04-20 21:25:44.125 557-632/? D/AlarmManager: Triggered Alarm 22ad4130
>   RTC_WAKEUP IntentSender{220fb650: PendingIntentRecord{2243b570
>   com.example.somelocation.myapplication broadcastIntent}} 04-20
>   21:25:44.125 557-557/? V/AlarmManager: triggered: flg=0x14
>   cmp=com.example.somelocation.myapplication/.MyAlarmReceiver

But i can't see any of my custom logs positioned inside my BroadcastReceiver or my IntentService.

MyTestService:

```
package com.example.somelocation.myapplication;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

public class MyTestService extends IntentService {
    public MyTestService() {
        super("MyTestService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        // Do the task here
        Log.i("MyTestService", "Service running"); // Can't see this log
    }
}
```

MyAlarmReceiver:

```
package com.example.somelocation.myapplication;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

public class MyAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public static final int REQUEST_CODE = 12345;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.e("MyTestService","broadcastreciever onReceive called"); // Can't see this log
        Intent i = new Intent(context, MyTestService.class);
        i.putExtra("foo", "bar");
        context.startService(i);
    }
}
```

Main Activity:

```
package com.example.somelocation.myapplication;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView batteryInfo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        scheduleAlarm();
    }

    public void scheduleAlarm() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyAlarmReceiver.class);
        final PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, MyAlarmReceiver.REQUEST_CODE,
                intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        long firstMillis = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
        AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarm.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, firstMillis,
               10000, pIntent);
    }
}
```

my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.somelocation.myapplication">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <receiver
                android:name=".MyAlarmReceiver"
                android:process=":remote" >
            </receiver>
            <service
                android:name=".MyTestService"
                android:exported="false"/>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

What am I missing?

***update:***
Got it! It was an error in my manifest file:
The close tag of the main activity was after the receiver declaration. should be:

```
    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name=".MyAlarmReceiver"
            android:process=":remote" >
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name=".BootReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"/>


</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

The log is being printed on the console... here is the log I am getting

```
04-22 18:30:28.421 1830-4146/com.example.somelocation.myapplication I/MyTestService: Service running
04-22 18:30:45.337 2641-2641/com.example.somelocation.myapplication:remote E/MyTestService: broadcastreciever onReceive called
04-22 18:30:45.344 1830-4394/com.example.somelocation.myapplication I/MyTestService: Service running
04-22 18:30:48.4032641-2641/com.example.somelocation.myapplication:remote E/MyTestService: broadcastreciever onReceive called
```

You are creating a separate process('remote') for the BroadcastReceiver and your logcat may be setup to display only the main process create at first.

See the screenshots - 
[image]
[image]

So change the application process from the dropdown and also select the log level to Verbose.

Comment: I disabled all filters and i still can't see it. thoughts?